# Question about Bounded Hilbert Operator and Riesz Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

I was dealing with this:

Let

\begin{equation}
[ \cdot, \cdot ] : H \times H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}
\end{equation}

such that $\forall x,y,z \in H$, $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{C}$,
$$ \langle x, \lambda y+\mu z\rangle  = \lambda \langle x, y \rangle + \mu \langle x, z \rangle,$$
$$\langle \lambda y+ \mu z, x \rangle = \bar{\lambda} \langle y,x \rangle + \bar{\mu} \langle z,x \rangle$$
$$\exists c\ge 0 : |\langle x,y \rangle| \le c\|x\| \|y\|.$$

> Show that there exists $A \in B(H)$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
> [ x,y ] = \langle Ax,y \rangle
> \end{equation}
>   (Bounded sesquilinear form)
>   and
>   \begin{equation}
> \|A\| = \min\{c \ge 0 : |\langle x, y \rangle| \le c\|x\| \|y\| \}
> \end{equation}

Of course one needs to recall the Riesz representation theorem to do this, but how, formally?

Comment: You might have left something out. As stated you could simply take $Ax = x$ for all $x$. That satisfies both conclusions.

Comment: nothing left out.. was that simple? First times dealing with this stuff..^_^"

Comment: As far as I know, the bounded sesquilinear form $A:\mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{C}$ is usually given, and then one should show that there is a unique bounded linear functional $B:\mathcal{H}\times\mathbb{C}$ such that $$A(x,y) = \langle Bx,y \rangle.$$

Comment: $\langle x,y \rangle$ is the inner product. What is the sesquilinear form that you are trying to represent?

Comment: Adding it.. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will  use the common convention in mathematics (as opposed to physics) where the conjugate linear coordinate is the second one.

For each $y$, consider the map $\phi_y(x)=x\longmapsto [x,y]$. This is linear, and 
$$
|\phi_y(x)|=[x,y]|\leq c \|x\|\,\|y\|. 
$$
So $\|\phi_y\|\leq c\|y\|$. By the Riesz Representation Theorem, there exists $z_y$ such that $[x,y]=\langle x,z_y\rangle$. So we have a function $B:H\to H$, given by $By=z_y$. This $B$ is linear by the uniqueness in the RRT. Also,
$$
\|By\|=\sup\{|\langle x,By\rangle|:\ \|x\|=1\}=\sup\{|[x,y]|:\ \|x\|=1\}\leq c\|y\|. 
$$
So $B$ is bounded with $\|B\|\leq c$, and if $A=B^*$, then $\|A\|=\|B^*\|=\|B\|\leq c$, and 
$$
[x,y]=\langle x,By\rangle=\langle Ax,y\rangle. 
$$